# url rewrite fails when trailing slash in the end is omitted

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have this to overwrite

http://mysite.com/intranet/symlinks/site.com to http://mysite.com/site.com

or

http://mysite.com/intranet/symlinks/site.net to http://mysite.com/site.net

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*\.com|.*\.net)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /intranet/symlinks/$1 [L]
```

It works perfectly for http://mysite.com/site.com/ ,

but if the link is http://mysite.com/site.com (notice the missing **/** in the end)

it will take me to http://mysite.com/intranet/symlinks/site.com/

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**: i think the problem lies to the Rule and not the Condition, since i removed the condition and keep having the same problem.i am redirected to http://mysite.com/intranet/symlinks/site.com/

**Edit 2** this is the rest of the .htaccess,its a default .htaccess from CodeIgniter:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# MY condition rule from above is located here

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyways i made it work using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*\.com/?.*|.*\.net/?.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/$1/ [L]
```

Notice the slash in the end of the second line after `$1`.

i am pretty sure it wont work for any other server setup, so if you have a better solution,post it and i will accept it

@LazyOne thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Change your line to optionally match the trailing `/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*\.com/?.*|.*\.net/?.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (you don't need a RewriteCond)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.(com|net))$ intranet/symlinks/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or this if you want to allow a trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.(com|net))/?$ intranet/symlinks/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i keep getting 404 errors for both of them :/ and i cant figure what is wrong with your statement

Comment: @rootatwc Do you have other rules in your .htaccess? Maybe they are one that causing this. Can you show the content of your .htaccess?

Comment: @rootatwc You have to Enable rewrite debugging and look yourself -- the rule written by @Floern works absolutely fine here (keep in mind, my setup can be completely different to yours).

Comment: @LazyOne , @Floern hmm,interesting i tested it on a different machine it works but it just redirects...it changes the URL.so if i type http://localhost/site.com it wont give a 404 error but it will redirect me to http://localhost/intranet/symlinks/site.com

Comment: @rootatwc If mod_rewrite triggers redirect, then it should have [R] flag in such rule (e.g. [R=301] for Permanent or [R=302] for Temporal). Maybe it is something else (another rule somewhere .. or even in a code -- we do not know your exact setup and can only guessing here). Anyway -- try enabling `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel 9` ans see what it ways .. otherwise you will be keep guessing and wondering why it does not work.

Comment: @LazyOne you are right.here is my log after a request to http://localhost/test.com  ... http://pastebin.com/gqndcYHg

Comment: @rootatwc Log clearly shows that rewrite does work fine. If you still having an error, that maybe because of the fact that you do not have any index file in that folder (e.g. `index.php`). Try putting some file there (e.g. `123.txt`) and access it via `localhost/test.com/123.txt` -- if everything is fine then you will see the content of that file (but for this you may need to have another rule .. as existing rule will only redirect hits to the folder itself).

Comment: nah, i have a index.php that prints hello world..i can see the contents the problem is that the url changes instead of staying http://localhost/test.com...the problem is the same with my initial RewriteRule..anyways i fixed it using `RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.(com|gr)/?.*)$ intranet/symlinks/$1/ [L,QSA]` but i really fill its hackish

Comment: @rootatwc So it's sorted -- congrats. You may now consider marking this answer as accepted ... or post your own answer -- at least other users will see that the problem was actually resolved.

Comment: yeah i posted my answer cause this rewrite rule keep giving me 404 on the server i want to deploy the app:)